# Selenium: Scroll through every page of an element with overflow auto

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

On a website we have an element with scrolbars generated with the css property `overflow` = `auto`.

How can I scroll through all pages of this element in a selnium test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the total height and the visible height of the element and then iterate through the pages while scrolling on each iteration.

```
let id = "some-id"; 
let divTotalHeight = await driver.executeScript("return document.getElementById(id).scrollHeight");
let divVisibleHeight = await driver.executeScript("return document.getElementById(id).clientHeight");
for (let i = 0; i * divVisibleHeight < divTotalHeight; i++) {
    // do something, e.g. take a screenshot
    await driver.executeScript("document.getElementById(id).scrollBy(0, " + divVisibleHeight + ")");
}
```